# Docker COPY from ubuntu absolute path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have following line in my dockerfile

```
COPY /root/url.net/volumes/persistent/url/root /usr/share/nginx/html
```

When I try to build the image with docker-compose I get

> Service 'frontend' failed to build: lstat
>   /root/url.net/volumes/persistent/url/root: no such file or
>   directory

I can cd from anywhere to `/root/url.net/volumes/persistent/url/root` with no problem on my machine.

How can I specify the absolute path of the folder in the dockerfile?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The absolute path of your resources refers to an absolute path within the build context, not an absolute path on the host. So all the resources must be copied into the directory where you run the docker build and then provide the path of those resources within your Dockerfiles before building the image. (This refers to the location where you run your Dockerfile)

There is a closed [**issue**](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4592) for this as well.

Comment: The docker daemon works on a copy of your provided context, possibly on another machine.  That copy is all you have to work with.

Answer (score 44):

You can't. You have to copy/hardlink the files/folders inside the directory where you build the docker image.