# dockefile-copy from absolute path

Tags: docker

Dockerfile is in `/home/user/docker` directory

I want to copy all files on host from `/app/publish` to the same path on docker container

```
WORKDIR /app
RUN cp /app/publish /app/
```

But getting

```
cp: cannot stat '/app/publish/': No such file or directory
```

I need to copy files outside of build context

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker COPY from ubuntu absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012495/docker-copy-from-ubuntu-absolute-path)

Comment: unfortunatelly, no :( i have buch of files and can't specify then individually

Comment: You need to include additional info. At what point do you need the host files to be available? If you need them at runtime just use a volume, in contrast if you need them at build time the link above answers the question.

Comment: i need then on build time

Comment: I think he wants to copy a file outside of build context.