# Docker and java sockets: Share data between containers

Tags: java, docker, sockets, stream

I'm coding a client-server service where my server is sending files to the client.

In the following example, I tried to send a list of file names to my client.

**Server**

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4000);
connsock = serverSocket.accept();
objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(connsock.getOutputStream());

List<String> file_names = new ArrayList<String>();
File[] files = new File("C:\\ServerMusicStorage").listFiles();

for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        file_names.add(file.getName());
    }
}
objectOutput.writeObject(file_names);
objectOutput.flush();
```

**Client**

```
newclientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 4000);
objectInput1 = new ObjectInputStream(newclientSocket.getInputStream());

System.out.println("<---Available files--->");

// get list of files from server
Object file_names = objectInput1.readObject();
file_list = (ArrayList<String>) file_names;
int count = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < file_list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(count + ")" + file_list.get(i));
    count++;
}
```

So when I run my program at *java NetBeans IDE* it works as I want. I get the files

```
<---Available files--->
1)blank.wav
2)fuark.wav
```

For the docker connection i created a network with

```
docker network create client_server_network
```

I run the server with

```
docker run --env SERVER_HOST_ENV=server --network-alias server --network client_server_network -it server
```

and the client with

```
docker run --network client_server_network -it clientimage
```

Although the *client-server connection is successful* through docker containers, when I run both services I don't get any output.

```
<---Available files--->
```

I'm stuck in this for days. What might be wrong? If I should provide any other information please tell me.

P.S. at the server-side of docker I set the *server* image as the host `newclientSocket = new Socket("server", 4000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Container have their own fileSystem different from the host filesystem.
Your path `C:\ServerMusicStorage` can't work in your container because this file is not in your container.

You should take a look to [bind](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) or [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/)

Or copying the file when creating your image.

Also your path is a windows path you should change it for an unix path (/yourdirectory) because most of docker images are linux system

If you want to use [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) in your DockerFile just add

```
COPY ServerMusicStorage/ /ServerMusicStorage
```

But if i'm not mistaken src file should be a relative path...  [related to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012495/docker-copy-from-ubuntu-absolute-path)
So you have to put /ServerMusicStorage near your build dir

Comment: i think this is a very clean answer. Can you please provide an example on how to copy my ```C:\ServerMusicStorage``` files to my image storage? I think the best way is to do it via ```COPY``` command on dockerfile?

Comment: I've changed my answer

Comment: Perfect, now how i can access my files? Although it  is sharing the *file names* with the solution you provided, when im trying to find a specific file i get that there is no such file```File song = new File("serverstorage\\" + requested_file + ".wav\\");``` what might be wrong?

Comment: use File song = new File("/serverstorage/" + requested_file + ".wav")
The slash at the start is necessary for absolute path