# Change nginx.conf file inside docker

Tags: docker, nginx, virtual-machine, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to create a reverse proxy using nginx running in docker. I have set up the nginx.conf file and it's running fine locally. However, I don't know how to set up the nginx docker with this changed nginx.conf file. Is there any way to do this?

Update: I have been able to change the nginx.conf file inside Docker. However, going to localhost:80/go returns a 502 Bad Gateway. I have a go app running on port 8081 using go run main.go and a python app running on port 8080 using flask run. I'm on a Manjaro VM.
This is the server part of the nginx.conf file

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location / {
        return 200 'hey there, welcome to our amazing app :)';
    }

    location /cbl {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location /go {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
    }
}
```

And this is the Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx
RUN mv /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginxorig.conf
#RUN pwd
#RUN cp /home/shark/hwr-nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
VOLUME /usr/share/nginx/html
VOLUME /etc/nginx
```

How do I fix this?

`````
[shark@shark-virtualbox hwr-nginx]$ sudo docker build . -t nginx
Sending build context to Docker daemon  7.168kB
Step 1/3 : FROM nginx
 ---> 7084cd82dcbb
Step 2/3 : RUN mv /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf_orig
 ---> Running in 80e011c5b125
mv: cannot stat '/etc/nginx/nginx.conf': No such file or directory
The command '/bin/sh -c mv /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf_orig' returned a non-zero code: 1
[shark@shark-virtualbox hwr-nginx]$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM nginx
RUN mv /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf_orig 
RUN cp hwr-nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```` RUN mv and RUN cp are also not working for me :(.
`````

Comment: Could you share a little bit more information? Like the command you are using to start the container? Which image you are using? Do you have a custom docker-file?

Comment: What do you want to know? The location of the Nginx's configuration file inside the container (Nginx image)?

Comment: I want to replace the nginx configuration file inside the container.

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy your nginx.conf to your container:

For example: `COPY conf /etc/nginx`

Docs here: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-docker/#managing-content-and-configuration-files

Comment: I tried copy, I got the error "COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat home/shark/hwr-nginx/nginx.conf: file does not exist" with the command COPY /home/shark/hwr-nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

Comment: Probably a problem with the way you specified the file/path. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012495/docker-copy-from-ubuntu-absolute-path

Answer (score 1):

In your `Dockerfile`, add an instruction to copy your project's reverse proxy configured `ngxin.conf`  into the docker image you intend to build, in the location where nginx will look for its configurations. For example, assuming your base image is Debian, you could do the following in your `Dockerfile`:

```
# Move the default conf out of the way
RUN mv /etc/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf_orig 
# Copy in your project's new nginx conf
RUN cp my_project/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```