# Podman cant find an existing absolute path to add

Tags: podman

I am using podman and trying to map an absolute path on my mac to `/opt/flatbuffers` on the container.

```
ADD /Users/bryan/src/git/flatbuffers /opt/flatbuffers
```

Getting this build error:

```
STEP 8/9: ADD /Users/bryan/src/git/flatbuffers /opt/flatbuffers
Error: error building at STEP "ADD /Users/bryan/src/git/flatbuffers /opt/flatbuffers": checking on sources under "/var/tmp/libpod_builder2832945314/build": copier: stat: "/Users/bryan/src/git/flatbuffers": no such file or directory
```

I have verified the absolute path exists and is populated.

Comment: You can't `COPY` or `ADD` arbitrary files into your image, they must be within the build-context directory.  See [Docker COPY from ubuntu absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012495/docker-copy-from-ubuntu-absolute-path), or [How to include files outside of Docker's build context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068596/how-to-include-files-outside-of-dockers-build-context) for some ways to work around it.  (I assume Podman has the same restriction.)

Comment: Thanks! So it seems a symlink is the only way.

Comment: Actually i need to link a directory and symlinks dont work either.