# Dockerfile, how to write certificate-ca folder?

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I can't connect to the terminal with SSH using Cloud Run (GCP). So, I plan to copy certificate.crt using DockerFile when uploading to container.

Linux is based on Debian. Backend code is stored in usr/src/app. But the path should be /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt'. The backend code works with the code below.

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY. .
COPY. ./
```

But what if I want to copy the file to /etc/ssl/certs/?

Now my node js cert file path is
It is located in project-name/etc/ssl/certs. (project-name/etc == project-name/src same level)

Comment: You may want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012495/docker-copy-from-ubuntu-absolute-path and https://serverfault.com/questions/666149/docker-copy-issue-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: @FonyLew that is totally different question why do you think it is same??

Comment: I think that it relates to the `COPY` command in the Dockerfile. Your question sounds like trying to COPY to an absolute path. I haven't tried it myself, but I think it's doable. Have you tried the accepted answer from the ServerFault one?

Comment: @FonyLew I am not copying files from a host absolute path. All files are moved from the node js project to the container.

Comment: Yes, I saw your answer. It shouldn't be a problem. 

Answer (score 1):

```
WORKDIR /etc/ssl/certs
COPY etc/ssl/certs/certificate.crt ./

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
...
```

I think it works