# How to add a local file to a container during Docker build with Docker Desktop?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-desktop

I would like to build a new image with docker build using docker desktop. It seems that the build context might not be available for the build process.

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.8.0-python3.8
ADD /tmp/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install apache-airflow==2.2.0 -r requirements.txt
```

It produces the following error:

```
❯ docker build - < Dockerfile_local
[+] Building 3.3s (6/7)                                                                                  docker:desktop-linux
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 195B                                                                                     0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/apache/airflow:2.8.0-python3.8                                                3.3s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                        0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                          0.0s
 => CANCELED [1/3] FROM docker.io/apache/airflow:2.8.0-python3.8@sha256:6d9a8f90ad5d6005f81b9a059134237f4f970b91d282799  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/apache/airflow:2.8.0-python3.8@sha256:6d9a8f90ad5d6005f81b9a059134237f4f970b91d282799a350f7dda  0.0s
 => => sha256:6d9a8f90ad5d6005f81b9a059134237f4f970b91d282799a350f7ddace6ab1a5 1.61kB / 1.61kB                           0.0s
 => => sha256:d7d27a316f5cd64a0b6eb87047ac04203c8b667a2c363e623bc326e8ea6665d7 25.67kB / 25.67kB                         0.0s
 => => sha256:180b4f3737b0430931e906094d02b0728912110b90c83ae7ffc467a0b01ba4fa 4.47kB / 4.47kB                           0.0s
 => ERROR [2/3] ADD /tmp/requirements.txt .                                                                              0.0s
------
 > [2/3] ADD /tmp/requirements.txt .:
------
Dockerfile:2
--------------------
   1 |     FROM apache/airflow:2.8.0-python3.8
   2 | >>> ADD /tmp/requirements.txt .
   3 |     RUN pip install apache-airflow==2.2.0 -r requirements.txt
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to compute cache key: failed to calculate checksum of ref f9dd9b67-5ecf-41ed-beed-87bfda7e1dfd::8el50kgcmxh0ay9r8ue7zhgp1: failed to walk /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount348437173/tmp: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount348437173/tmp: no such file or directory

View build details: docker-desktop://dashboard/build/desktop-linux/desktop-linux/10tveo6gaue4pbz92r0mnwvgc
```

Is there a way to share a file with the build context like this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker COPY from ubuntu absolute path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47012495/docker-copy-from-ubuntu-absolute-path)

Comment: I dont think it does. I need to understand why does not the docker build ship the context together with my file to the build process.

Comment: My mistake! I've overlooked this in your post: `docker build - < Dockerfile_local`.

Answer (score 0):

Move the requirements.txt to the same path as Dockerfile and then change the ADD command to:

ADD requirements.txt .

If this works, thsi will serve as a sanity check that will allow you to narrow the problem to the tmp path.

Comment: This is only part of the solution. You forgot to point out that the way the OP was building the image - `docker build - < Dockerfile_local` - was problematic. Take a look at @OlakunleAbiola's answer.